# How to match against a set of possible values?

Tags: scala

I have a set and I want to match another variable against any one of its elements. I know I can do this manually like this:

```
fruits = Set("a", "b", "c", "d")
toMatch = ("a", "fruit")
toMatch match {
   case (("a" | "b" | "c" | "d", irrelevant)) => true
}
```

But is there any way to use fruits in the match statement, so I don't have to manually expand it

EDIT: I currently am using an if condition to do this, I was wondering if there is some syntactic sugar I can use to do it inline

```
fruits = Set("a", "b", "c", "d")
toMatch = ("a", "fruit")
toMatch match {
   case ((label, irrelevant)) if fruits.contains(label) => true
}
```

If there is no other answer, Ill mark the first person who responded with if as the solution ! Sorry about the lack of clarity there.

EDIT2: The reason for this if you are wondering is

```
fruits = Set("a", "b", "c", "d")
vegetables = Set("d", "e", "f")
toMatch = ("a", "fruit")
toMatch match {
   case ((label, "fruit")) if fruits.contains(label) => true
   case ((label, "vegetable")) if vegetables.contains(label) => true
}
```

I would like to combine the two cases so i have one condition for each return type

Comment: I currently use an if statement for doing this, but was wondering if there is some syntactic sugar to do this

Comment: Do you mean like `fruits.contains("a")` (or whatever) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with 'if' statement in match

```
  val fruits = Set("a", "b", "c", "d")
  val toMatch = ("a", "otherVar")

  toMatch match {
    case (fruit, _) if fruits.contains(fruit) => true
  }
```

Comment: I currently use an if statement for doing this, but was wondering if there is some syntactic sugar to do this!

Comment: 'if' statement is exactly syntactic sugar for it

Comment: `fruits(fruit)` should be equivalent to `fruits.contains(fruit)`

Comment: The reason for the question was mainly to do this, if toMatch._1 matches set fruits, and irrelevant = "a" or toMatch._2 matches another set vegetables and irrelevant = "b" answer true. With the if statements, I need to use two cases that return the same result. If a better solution does not exist, ill mark yours as the solution

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the two cases then using 'if' or @Eugene answer is enough, but for more cases I would use a Map:

```
val fruits = Set("a", "b", "c", "d")
val vegetables = Set("d", "e", "f")
val meats = Set("q", "w")

val food = Map("fruits" -> fruits, "vegetables" -> vegetables, "meats" -> meats)

val toMatch = ("a", "fruit")

scala> food(toMatch._2)(toMatch._1)
res3: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom extractor to get this syntactic sugar you desire:

```
object FruitAndVegetable {
  val fruits = Set("a", "b", "c", "d")
  val vegetables = Set("d", "e", "f")

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    List(
      "a" -> "fruit",
      "a" -> "vegetable",
      "d" -> "fruit",
      "d" -> "vegetable",
      "e" -> "fruit",
      "f" -> "vegetable"
    ) foreach {
      toMatch =>
        val result = toMatch match {
          case CustomExtractor(`fruits`, "fruit") => "found a fruit"
          case CustomExtractor(`vegetables`, "vegetable") => "veggy"
          case _ => "Neither fruit nor veggy"
        }
        println(result)
    }
  }

  object CustomExtractor {
    def unapply(toMatch: (String, String)): Option[(Set[String], String)] =
      if ((fruits contains toMatch._1) && toMatch._2 == "fruit") Some(fruits -> toMatch._2)
      else if (vegetables contains toMatch._1) Some(vegetables -> toMatch._2)
      else None
  }

}
```

However, note that there are three problems with this approach (maybe more that I can't think of):

- `CustomExtractor` has a dependency to the `fruits` and `vegetables` collection, aswell as to `"fruit"`. Reason: we want to extract a `Set[String]` from a `String`(because we match against the set), so we need to find a set which contains the string, i.e., `fruits` and `vegetables`. Since the sets are not distinct, we also need to know which set to return in case `toMatch._1` is contained in both sets (here: `"d"`). In this case, we need to look at `toMatch._2`.
- `CustomExtractor` still needs to implement the "unfancy" matching (though you could do it more elegantly than what I did)
- Your `case`-statements get "polluted" by the object identifier `CustomExtractor`(or whatever you want to call it)

I would only consider this solution if you have a lot of `match`-statements that match on those values. In that case, you only need to write the extractor once and can reuse it.

**PS**: I am not very familiar with extractors, so maybe you can come up with a better way to solve this problem using extractors.

Comment: Actually, I am not sure if I did grasp the question. If the extraction is **independent on the second element**, then you can change the return type of ``unapply`` to ``Option[Set[String]]`` and remove the checks on ``toMatch._2``. Obviously, this makes the second tuple element irrelevant, and `"a" -> "vegetable"` will match to `fruit` as well as `"d" -> "vegetable"` and `"a" -> "not even food"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another custom unapply method idea you can use that is a bit more type-safe.

```
object CustomExtractor {
  case class Group(label: String, values: Set[String])
}

class CustomExtractor {
  private[this] val labelMap = mutable.HashMap[String, CustomExtractor.Group]()

  def newMatcher(label: String, values: String*): CustomExtractor.Group = {
    if (labelMap.contains(label)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Label Already Mapped: ${labelMap(label)}")
    }

    labelMap.getOrElseUpdate(label, new CustomExtractor.Group(label, Set(values: _*)))
  }

  def unapply(toMatch: (String, String)): Option[CustomExtractor.Group] = {
    val (value, label) = toMatch
    labelMap.get(label).filter(_.values.contains(value))
  }
}

val extractor = new CustomExtractor
val fruits = extractor.newMatcher("fruit", "a", "b", "c", "d")
val vegetables = extractor.newMatcher("vegetable", "d", "e", "f")

val tests = List("a" -> "fruit", "a" -> "vegetable", "d" -> "fruit", "d" -> "vegetable", "e" -> "fruit", "f" -> "vegetable")

for (test <- tests) {
  test match {
    case extractor(`fruits`) => println(s"$test is definitely a fruit.")
    case extractor(group) => println(s"$test was matched to ${group.label}.")
    case _ => println(s"$test was not matched!")
  }
}
```